# Sequelize TypeError: defineCall is not a function

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

Working on an express project with a SQLite database.

I'm getting an Sequelize TypeError that I've been working on for hours but I'm coming up against a brick wall:

```
   C:\-----\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:392
          this.importCache[path] = defineCall(this, DataTypes);
                                   ^

    TypeError: defineCall is not a function
        at Sequelize.import (C:\----\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:392:32)
 at C:\----\models\index.js:25:32
```

After doing some research, it appears that this could be caused when trying to import a non-sequelize object. Below is the problematic index.js file.

index.js:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

var config = {
  dialect: 'sqlite',
  storage: 'library.db'
};

var connection = new Sequelize(config);
var contents = fs.readdirSync(__dirname);
var db = {};


contents = contents.filter(function(file){

  var currFileName = __filename.split('/');
  var checkOne = file.substr(file.length - 3, 3) === '.js';
  var checkTwo = file !== currFileName[currFileName.length - 1];

  return checkOne && checkTwo;
});

contents.forEach(function(file){
  var path = [__dirname, file].join('/');
  var model = connection.import(path);

  db[model.name] = model;
});

Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName){
  var model = db[modelName];

  if(model.associate) {
    model.associate(db);
  }
});


module.exports = {
  models: db,
  connection: connection
};
```

I do not have any function called defineCall, any idea where the error is coming from?

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed caused by importing a file that's not a Sequelize model. In my case, it was because my `index.js` was pulling in my test files as well as the models, which were in the same directory. Try adding another check like `checkOne` to exclude anything that ends with `.test.js`.

Answer (score 0):

With the hint from the answer by @Floppy, I got to realise that it would be better if we stored those related files encapsulated in a folder.

For eg. make a folder named `Models` and store your `index.js` with all the models (eg. User model, photos model, etc) and then try.

Thanks.